# What is the correct REST endpoint for adding an item to an array field?

Tags: mongodb, rest

Say I'm trying to model the action of adding a Student to a Group in a RESTful API written in Go with MongoDB.

A Group is modeled like this:

```
type Group struct {
Section mgo.DBRef
Instructor mgo.DBRef
Students []mgo.DBRef
}
```

An additional constraint is that the API is implementing [HAL+JSON](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) protocol, where resources are represented as links.

I've seen a couple of options (below):

- POST /groups/{groupID}/students/{studentID} will add student with studentID to the group. The problem with this approach is that since I'm implementing the HAL+JSON protocol, I don't want the client to have manually pull out the ID and generate this link. All resources will be represented, i.e. `/person/123` could be a Student.
- PUT  /groups/{groupID} while sending the complete array of Students that should belong to the group. This seems like it will introduce a lot of complicated parsing logic.

If there are other options I'd be open to it too.

EDIT: The approach that I'm going with is the following:
* POST /groupmembership/ by sending a JSON with the ID of the student and the ID of the group to add the student to. However, on the backend, I'm not generating a new model, but instead taking the object and programmatically adding the specified student to the specified group.

The question then is how would I remove the Student from the Group? Can I similar send a DELETE request to /groupmembership with

```
{
  "student": 123,
  "group": 456
}
```

to remove student 123 from group 456?

Answer (score 3):

> where resources are represented as links

This is not true. Links are possibly operations calls, so they are representing possible resource state transitions.

To add something to a collection, you need a collection resource and you have to decide what you want to store in that collection. In your case this can be 2 things: group-student memberships or students. If this is an 1:n relation, then you can store students and remove students. If this is an n:m relation then you have to store memberships and remove memberships, since you don't want to remove the students from your storage, just the memberships.

You can identify the memberships 2 ways:

- you can use the ids of the participants: `/groups/1/memberships/student:1` or `/students/1/memberships/group:1`
- you can add a unique id to each membership: `/memberships/1234`

notes:

- The URI structure matters only from a human perspective. The REST client will check the link relations and not the URI structure.
- The resources are different from the entities in your database. Only by simple CRUD application represent them the same thing. So REST has nothing to do with your database structure.

Comment: The problem is that you're allowing an artifact from an underlying relational database - the need for a link table in an n:m relation -  to leak into the API design. The API doesn't have to map directly to the database models. The API doesn't need the membership resource to represent a student present in many groups.

Comment: Nobody said, that you need to have a relational database or the API has to map to the database models. The membership is a REST best practice for n:m relations. If you don't have additional meta-data and you don't want to add an aggregate id to the memberships, then you can simply use the `/memberships/group:{groupId}+student:{studentId}` URL.

Comment: The need for a link table is implied, which is an artifact from relational database design. There's no such thing as a REST best practice for n:m relations, since REST has no say on URL semantics and modelling. Even if there's metadata and it's stored as a membership link table in a relational database, there's no need for the membership resource in the REST API.

Comment: According to you... https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=5WXYw4J4QOU#t=3951

Comment: Btw REST has nothing to do with domain model or relational database structure, it is just a delivery method, so I don't know what you are talking about...

Comment: Precisely. REST has nothing to do with domain model, yet, your answer suggests a design that is an artifact from the limitations of relational databases and isn't necessary. I see you're having a hard time to understand that, so forget it. I'm not going to argue all day.

Comment: Actually what I suggest has nothing to do with relational databases. Yes maybe it is similar the way you model memberships in relational databases, but that is just a coincidence.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, there's no correct REST endpoint. URL semantics are irrelevant to REST. All that matters is that URLs are obtained from hypertext and not from out-of-band information, and seems like you got that part right, since you're using HAL. So, the correct REST endpoint is whatever link your server gives to the clients in order to add the item.

As long as an option isn't incorrect from an HTTP standpoint, I'd say to stick with whatever is more consistent with the REST of your API.

The option to `POST /groups/{groupID}/students/{studentID}` in order to create a new student in that location is incorrect, since a POST is submitting the payload to be processed by the targeted resource, and in this case it doesn't exist yet. A common pattern is to use `POST /groups/{groupID}/students`, where the collection acts as a facory for new elements, with the creation parameters in the payload, and returning the created student URL in the Location header, with 201 HTTP status code.